# Alternative for deprecated endorsed-standards override mechanism and extension mechanism

Tags: java, java-8, java-9

The [release notes for Java 8 Update 40 (8u40)](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml) state:

> The endorsed-standards override mechanism and the extension mechanism
>   are deprecated and may be removed in a future release. There are no
>   runtime changes. Existing applications using the 'endorsed-standards
>   override' or 'extension' mechanisms are recommended to migrate away
>   from using these mechanisms.

There is also the issue which clarifies that with Jigsaw (planned for Java SE 9, AFAIK) this will be replaced with a modular approach somehow:

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=8065675

I understand that Oracle wants to deprecate these mechanisms now because they cannot support them in Java SE 9 anymore.

On the other hand, it's not a good practice to deprecate something without providing an alternative.

The release notes state: "Existing applications [...] are recommended to migrate away from using these mechanisms"

So how can you "migrate away from"

- endorsed-standards override mechanism
- extension mechanism

in Java SE 8?

Comment: Where does it say it can't be supported in Java 9?

Comment: @EJB That's what I understood. E.g. in the issue:  "Going forward we expect to support endorsed standards and standalone APIs in modular form only, via the concept of upgradeable modules [2]." Maybe I also read something about this in other resources. And AFAIK Jigsaw is planned for Java SE 9. But again, this is at least my current understandig not necessarily a fact. Do you have other information regarding this?

Comment: 'Going forward' != Java 9. You're panicking unduly. They haven't mentioned a target release or a timeline. I would think you're safe until at least one major release has passed with both mechanisms present: maybe two or more.

Comment: @EJP, maybe you are right. Still, are there ways to "migrate away from" as they suggest in the 8u40 release notes, so we can prepare for the new situation and avoid using deprecated features? Or is this only possible with Jigsaw (but then the suggestion is at least confusing at this time)?

Comment: @EJP Some background information: This is not only a theoretical question, but I'm currently in a situation where I think I have to use an endorsed library in a framework I'm writing. Reading these release notes I realize I will use something that is already deprecated. So my question: Is there a better way at the time? The related question is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26769891/osgi-javax-annotation-conflict-java-se-vs-java-ee

Comment: @EJP: They are indeed planned to be removed in Java SE 9. I found another article. See my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I found the following article, which explains that these mechanisms are indeed planned to be removed in Java SE 9:

https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/planning_safe_removal_of_under

Unfortunately there doesn't seem much you can do now, e.g. for libraries which are part of the JRE.

> **What to do if you are affected**
>
> Although most applications do not use
>   the endorsed standards or extension mechanism, some applications do.
>   If you are a developer, please consider providing dependencies as part
>   of your application rather than requiring external system
>   configurations. If you are not the developer, please contact the
>   individual software vendor for support.

Answer (score 2):

With Java 8 you can keep using the deprecated mechanism.  Oracle is only offering a way to check if your application makes use of the mechanism with this java.exe flag `-XX:+CheckEndorsedAndExtDirs` [[1](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/planning-safe-removal-of-under-used-endorsed-extension-directories)] available in Java 8 update 40 and later.

When you upgrade to Java 9, to avoid your Java application failing at runtime, with NoClassDefFoundError caused by ClassNotFoundException like

```
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-3" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/rmi/CORBA/Stub
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.jacorb.orb.ORB._getDelegate(ORB.java:541)
        at org.jacorb.orb.ORB.string_to_object(ORB.java:2110)
--snip--
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.rmi.CORBA.Stub
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 26 more
```

you'll need to update your java.exe launch command-lines with arguments like
    --add-modules
    --patch-module
    -add-exports

For a specific example, see Grzegorz Grzybek's September 2016 post on the jacorb-developer mailing [[2](http://lists.spline.inf.fu-berlin.de/pipermail/jacorb-developer/2016-September/000828.html)].  We had to update our application's Windows batch file with the Java 9 additional command-line arguments like

```
java --add-modules "java.corba" --patch-module "java.corba=..\lib\jacorb-omgapi-3.4.jar" --add-exports=java.corba/org.omg.CONV_FRAME=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.corba/org.omg.CORBA_2_5=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.corba/org.omg.PortableGroup=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.corba/org.omg.ETF=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.corba/org.omg.GIOP=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.corba/org.omg.SSLIOP=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=java.corba/org.omg.CSIIOP=ALL-UNNAMED -jar ourapp.jar
```

One footnote relevant to CORBA and Java, CORBA (and JAXB) are slated for complete removal in Java 11.  See "JEP 320: Remove the Java EE and CORBA Modules" [[3](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/320)] and this blog post [[4](http://marxsoftware.blogspot.com/2018/02/early-jeps-java-11.html)].

Answer (score -1):

Your fallback right now is to explicitly list your classpath directories and jar files when you execute the java instance.

Comment: The "normal" classpath can not replace classes provided by the JRE, AFAIK.

Comment: Those provided by the JRE are default.  Extensions have been externally added to the JRE path by the user, and is considered generally an anti-pattern.  I've never used the endorsed-dirs feature ever.  All external dependencies are best listed on the classpath.  Anything you had in extensions should instead be provided as a .jar or class directory, also on the classpath.  That's my view on it anyway.