# Is there any difference between using imported libraries and java extensions?

Tags: java, performance, websocket

I'm doing a project that uses websockets and I was using the Okhttp3 library, but I was wondering if there would be a performance difference in the connection if I decided to use javax.websocket instead. If there is a performance difference, would it be minute or massive?

Answer (score 2):

1. There should be no appreciable<sup>1</sup> performance difference between extension and external libraries.  And none at all once the code has been loaded.
2. The Java extension mechanism was deprecated in Java 8u40 (2015-03-03) and was removed in Java 9. **So you shouldn't be contemplating using it.**

See [Alternative for deprecated endorsed-standards override mechanism and extension mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28983922).

---

<sup>1 - It is conceivable that there could be small differences due to having to load the index for an extra JAR file, or due to the Java installation and the external JAR being on different file systems with different performance characteristics.  But these should only affect performance at JVM startup.</sup>